# Summing over trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function in explicit formulas

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

[Formulas for prime-counting functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Formulas_for_prime-counting_functions)
$$\tag{1.a}\psi _{0}(x)=x-\sum _{\rho }{\frac {x^{\rho }}{\rho }}-\ln 2\pi -{\frac {1}{2}}\ln(1-x^{-2})$$

$$\tag{2.a}\Pi _{0}(x)=\operatorname {li} (x)-\sum _{\rho }\operatorname {li} (x^{\rho })-\ln 2+\int _{x}^{\infty }{\frac {dt}{t(t^{2}-1)\ln t}}$$

$$\tag{3.a}\pi _{0}(x)=\operatorname {R} (x)-\sum _{\rho }\operatorname {R} (x^{\rho })-{\frac {1}{\ln x}}+{\frac {1}{\pi }}\arctan {\frac {\pi }{\ln x}}$$

Thus corresponding sums over trivial zeros are:
$$\tag{1.b}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2 n}}{-2 n}=-{\frac {1}{2}}\ln(1-x^{-2})$$
$$\tag{2.b}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\operatorname {li} (x^{-2 n})=\int _{x}^{\infty }{\frac {dt}{t(t^{2}-1)\ln t}}$$
$$\tag{3.b}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\operatorname {R} (x^{-2 n})=-{\frac {1}{\ln x}}+{\frac {1}{\pi }}\arctan {\frac {\pi }{\ln x}}$$

I can verify $(1.b)$ by series expansion of $\log (x+1)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n}$ around x=0 and then substituting $x\to-x^{-2}$.

**How do we verify or derive $(2.b)$ and $(3.b)?$**

Another related question:

I can compute residue at s=0 in $(1.a)$ which is equal $-\ln 2\pi$ by using Taylor expansion.

**But how can we compute residues at s=0 which appear in $(2.a)$ as  $-\ln 2$ and in $(3.a)$ as $0$?**

Comment: if you understand 1.b then 2.b is obvious. I don't see what you mean with residue at $s=0$ in 2.a. Do you realize 1.a is an explicit formula for $\psi(x)$, thus an explicit formula for $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ ? From which you deduce an explicit formula $\log \zeta(s)$ and the Hadamard factorization of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @reuns Yes, that was going to be my next question here... How do we derive Hadamard factorization of $\zeta(s)$. Tomorrow I will try to explain $(2.b)$ in my own answer as that you said it is obvious. I think I know how, but it is too late now for proper thinking.

Comment: @reuns What I meant by residue at s=0 in $(2.a)$ is this: $\Pi _{0}(x)=\frac{1}{2\ \pi\ i}\int_{a-\infty\ i}^{a+\infty\ i}\log\zeta(s)\,\frac{x^s}{s}\ ds$.

Comment: $\log \zeta(s)$ isn't meromorphic (infinitely many branch points at $1,\rho,-2k$) so the residue theorem doesn't apply to $\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{a-\infty\ i}^{a+\infty\ i}\log\zeta(s)\,\frac{x^s}{s}\ ds$

Comment: @reuns There is always some problem with branch points! And do you have any hints on $(3.b)$?

Answer (score 0):

So here is my attempt on $(2.b)$ (which I do not consider very obvious):
$$-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{\operatorname {li} (x^{-2 n})}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int _{0}^{x^{-2 n}}{\frac {1}{\ln t}\,dt}}$$

Using substitution $t=u^{-2 n}$ so that $dt=-2 n\,u^{-2 n-1} du$:

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int _{\infty}^{x}{\frac {-2 n\,u^{-2 n-1}}{\ln(u^{-2 n})}\,du}}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int _{\infty}^{x}{\frac {-2 n\,u^{-2 n-1}}{-2 n \ln u}\,du}}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int _{x}^{\infty}{\frac {-u^{-2 n-1}}{\ln u}\,du}}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\int _{x}^{\infty}{\frac {u^{-2 n}}{u \ln u}\,du}}=\int _{x}^{\infty}{\frac {\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{u^{-2 n}}}{u \ln u}\,du}=\int _{x}^{\infty}{\frac {1/(u^2-1)}{u \ln u}\,du}=\int _{x}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{u (u^2-1) \ln u}\,du}$$

So $(3.b)$ still remains open, so feel free to comment or answer on this one.
...and also the "residue question" still open.